# Convert XML to and from Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, jackson-databind

I am trying to get the XML response from the rest API. And I am getting JSON response for all customers and XML for single customer from API. PFB the screen print for the case for both cases:

Case 1: When URL= http://localhost:8080/spring-crm-rest/api/customers/ then I am getting JSON response
[JSON Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUr0j.png)

Case 2: When URL = http://localhost:8080/spring-crm-rest/api/customers/1 then I am getting XML response
[XML Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ8QH.png)

Please find below the URL for the complete code to replicate the same at your end.
Link for the code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fd7DyUsfOvY4fX0nm6j4fzrwxHyg9ZGz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, please put the relevant code snippets in your question. It makes it easier to read, and most users won't download your project just to read your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think the reason why that happens is the following:
the path `/spring-crm-rest/api/customers/` has return type `List<Customer>` -> default java List as top level -> json result

while `/spring-crm-rest/api/customers/1` has return type `Customer` as top level which has the javax.xml.bind annotations -> xml result

Changing this may be a bit tricky but these are some possible things you can try:

1. specifically set the content type of the endpoint like this: `@GetMapping(produces = {"application/json"})`
2. removing the `@Xml.*` annotations -> spring will can serialize the class without any annotations but without them you have less of a control over the resulting json (e.g. renaming fields, etc). Depending on your usecase it might not be needed though